# How to solve consecutive question using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello guys I am facing problem to solve a problem. The problem is as below:
 Create an array of length 10 with random values from range 1-99. Then count the tens value and
show it as consecutive *. Try to be logical in this question and don’t hard-code this part eg. >0
and <10. Think how you can implement the same code for bigger ranges like 1-999 without
increasing the code length. For example:
o If array = [9,19,28,29,45,50,51,52,86,97] then it shows:
 0-9 : *
 10-19 : *
 20-29 : **
 30-39 :
 40-49 : *
 50-59 : ***
 60-69 :
 70-79 :
 80-89 : *
 90-99 : *

Till now I am able to do the following only:

```js
// console.log(Math.random()*(100-0)+ 0);
const totalNumber = 10;

let arr = [];

for(i=0;i<=totalNumber;i++){
    let random = Math.random()*(100-0)+ 0; //getting random value
    arr.push(Math.round(random)); //pushing it with round value
}
//sorting it 
arr.sort();
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

### I do this task like this

```js
const totalNumber = 10;

let arr = [];
let objects= {}
for(i=0;i<=totalNumber;i++){
    let random = Math.random()*100;
    arr.push(Math.round(random)); 
}

arr.sort();

for(i=0;i<totalNumber;i++){
 objects[`${i*10}-${((i+1)*10)-1}`]=arr.filter(x=>((i+1)*10)>x)
 objects[`${i*10}-${((i+1)*10)-1}`]=
 objects[`${i*10}-${((i+1)*10)-1}`].filter(x=>x>=(i*10))
}

for (const key in objects) {
if(objects[key].length===0){
delete objects[key]
}
}
 console.log(objects)
```

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? @user11437679

Answer (score 1):

```js
let min = 0;
let max = 9;
let final = 999;
let arr = [1,2,27,33,44,56,71,81,991];
let count = 0;
let star = "";
while(max <= final){
    for(i = 0;i<=arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]>min && arr[i]<max){
            //save in array
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(j = 0;j<count;j++){
        star += "*";
    }
    console.log(min + " - "+ max + " : "+ star);
    min =  min +10;
    max = max + 10;
    count = 0;
    star = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` through `arr` and output to a new array with indices as the tens place of the range you're working with. Something like:

```
rangecount=[] // rangecount[0] holds the number of values 0-9, etc.
arr.forEach( (e) => {
  const group = Math.floor(e/10);
  if (rangecount[group]) {
    rangecount[group]++;
  } else {
    rangecount[group] = 1;
  }
});
```

Now you have an array that contains each group, so you just need to construct the relevant strings.

```
const countSymbol = "*";
const output = rangecount.map( (e,i) => `${i*10} to ${i*10+9}: ${countSymbol.repeat(e)}`).filter(e => e);
console.table(output);
```

The filter at the end takes out nulls, in case some of the ranges are empty. Implementation is a little different if you want to include every section of the range of your random numbers.

You can see my version of the solution here: https://codepen.io/horsedreamer/pen/mdJmQjb